# unique_ptr usage in c++

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

How do I pass the `unique_ptr` in the below code? This code does not compile.

```
int abc(int*& a)
{  
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World";
    std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int); 
    abc(a.get());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `unique_ptr::get` returns raw pointer by value, you cannot bind Rvalue (temporary object) - `a.get()` to non-const Lvalue reference. Change signature of `abc` to `abc(int*)` or `abc(int* const &)`.

Comment: adding to @darune's answer you have to use the following:
    std::unique_ptr<int> a = std::make_unique<int>();
    abc(a);
you can't initialize smart pointers like
    std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int);

Comment: @shesharp That's incorrect. Especially considering that [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) wasn't introduced until the C++14 standard, while [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) was introduced in the C++11 standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for pointing that out! I thought error was due to  std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int); Im used to using it with make_unique i thought it was wrong.

Comment: @shesharp `std::unique_ptr` has a constructor that takes a raw pointer as input. It takes ownership of the memory being pointed to

Answer (score 1):

You may pass it by const reference or reference for example:

```
int abc(const std::unique_ptr<int>& a)
```